# Compass: syntax to generate sprite images, with a specific state on the parent item (:hover, .class)

Tags: css, css-sprites, compass-sass, sass

I would like to use SASS & [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) to generate some specific sprites.

This is the code I have, without Compass/Sprite:

```
.ico-account-contact-informations { 
    width:60px; height:40px; background:url(/images/ico-account/contact-informations.png);
    a[href]:hover &, .fn-active & {background:url(/images/ico-account/contact-informations_active.png);} 
} 
.ico-account-credit-cards { 
    width:60px; height:40px; background:url(/images/ico-account/credit-cards.png); 
    a[href]:hover &, .fn-active & {background:url(/images/ico-account/credit-cards-active_active.png);} 
}
```

I need the same structure with a sprite image.
I read the "[magical part](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)" of the sprite tutorial, but I can't find the correct syntax to do what I need.

---

For exemple I tried that:

```
$ico-account-sprite-dimensions: true;    
@include all-ico-account-sprites();
a {@include all-ico-account-sprites();}
```

But with that, the state :hover is on the "img" but not on the "a".

---

I also tried that:

```
$ico-account-sprite-dimensions: true;    
@import "ico-account/*_hover.png";
a[href]:hover {@include all-ico-account-sprites(true);}
@import "ico-account/*.png";
@include all-ico-account-sprites(true);
```

Now it generate multiple variants of css class name, but not the case for:

```
a[href]:hover .ico-account-credit-cards {...}
```

And there is 2 sprites instead of 1.

---

Not so easy for me... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution.
It can be done on a case by case basis for all images where we need to support an active (or :hover) state:

```
/* Mixin */
@mixin link-bg-sprite($map, $img, $img-active: $img + '_active') {
    .#{sprite-map-name($map)}-#{$img} {
        background: sprite($map, $img) no-repeat;
        width: image-width(unquote("/" + sprite-map-name($map) + "/" + $img + ".png"));
        height: image-height(unquote("/" + sprite-map-name($map) + "/" + $img + ".png"));
        a[href]:hover &, .fn-state-active & {
            background: sprite($map, $img-active) no-repeat;
        }
    }
}

/* Account Icons */
$map: sprite-map("ico-account/*.png");
@include link-bg-sprite($map, contact-informations);
@include link-bg-sprite($map, credit-cards);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of magic in compass and its sprites.

You don't have to add any mixins or code, to add states for Sprites in Compass.
You can add states to your sprites by naming them in the right way:

```
icons/myfirstsprite.png         <- the path to a sprite
icons/myfirstsprite_hover.png   <- this image will automatically generate 
                                   a css hover state for "myfirstsprite.png"
```